# How to make Play scrubbable?

Tags: sound

For longer audio clips, the functionality provided by `Play` or `Sound` is clunky. I find myself wanting to scrub through with a slider to a part that I want to hear. Has anyone seen such a function or package?

For example, I don't want to wait through 90 seconds just to hear the last 10 seconds:

```
Sound[SoundNote[#, 1, RandomChoice[{"Piano", "Cello", "Tuba"}]] & /@ 
  RandomInteger[12, 300], 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f = Sound[SoundNote[#, 1, RandomChoice[{"Piano", "Cello", "Tuba"}]] & /@ 
          RandomInteger[12, 300], 100];
{sounds, duration} = List @@ f;
durs = sounds /. SoundNote[p_, d_, i_] :> d /. SoundNote[p_, i_] :> 1;
steps = Rescale[Most@Prepend[Accumulate@durs, 0]];

Manipulate[Sound[sounds[[s ;;]], duration (1 - steps[[s]]) ], 
          {s, Range@Length@steps, ControlType -> Slider}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The temporal scale in the slider may turn non-linear if the sounds have different durations, but it's quite easy to manage and it doesn't seem worth entangling this code. (you can find it in the edit history of this answer)

Comment: Elegant solution! Is there anyway to remove the bottom pane  (the one that's just gray)?

Comment: @M.R. Thanks. No idea how to do that,sorry